# My Ionic application will not run without active network connection

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have an Ionic application that loads some data from a server, and it works just fine on browser. However, when I try to run it on an android device, the application doesn't work when there's no network connection (data, WiFi, etc).

It shows a message "Webpage not available", and the Ionic Ready function is not even being called.

So my question is, does anyone know how to fix this? I want to be able to run my application even without a network connection.

Comment: How will you access data from a server without network connection?

Comment: In that case I will get the data from local storage. But the point here is that when there's no connection the application does not run and shows a message on webview that sais "Webpage not available".

Comment: Are you getting that error on an actual android phone or on a simulator

Comment: Does the same behavior happen on the simulator? If so I would run it on that and debug it. Sorry I don't know that I can be of more help without seeing some source code :/

Comment: What do the ADB logs say?: https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/12/debugging-android-source-code-adb/